# 4x4 matrix multiplication order

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, webgl, matrix-multiplication

I"m using the following library:

https://github.com/greggman/tdl/blob/master/tdl/math.js

however, the question is about different results i'm getting when i take the same steps in different ways:

```
//Example 1
m = tdl.math.matrix4.identity();
tdl.math.matrix4.rotateX( m, 90*(Math.PI/180 ) );
tdl.math.matrix4.translate( m, [10,20,30]);

console.log (m); //output down below 1

//Example2
i = tdl.math.matrix4.identity();
r = tdl.math.matrix4.rotationX( 90*(Math.PI/180 ) );
t = tdl.math.matrix4.translation( [10,20,30] );
m = tdl.math.matrix4.mul( i, r );
m = tdl.math.matrix4.mul( m, t );

console.log( m ); // output down below 2
```

Both ways have the same order of actions, namely

1. identity
2. rotate 90 deg around x
3. translate by 10x, 20y

However, the output is not the same, here is output 1:

```
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6.123233995736766e-17, 1, 0, 0, -1, 6.123233995736766e-17, 0, 10, -30, 20.000000000000004, 1]
```

here is output 2

```
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6.123233995736766e-17, 1, 0, 0, -1, 6.123233995736766e-17, 0, 10, 20, 30, 1]
```

Why is the outcome different, when i'm seemingly taking the same steps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because multiplication of matrices is different depending on which matrix is on the left. In other words

```
matA * matB != matB * matA
```

Try

```
i = tdl.math.matrix4.identity();
r = tdl.math.matrix4.rotationX( 90*(Math.PI/180 ) );
t = tdl.math.matrix4.translation( [10,20,30] );
m = tdl.math.matrix4.mul( r, i );
m = tdl.math.matrix4.mul( t, m );

console.log( m ); // output down below
```

Outputs

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6.123031769111886e-17, 1, 0, 0, -1, 6.123031769111886e-17, 0, 10, -30, 20.000000000000004, 1]
```

Comment: I can see that, however, this only happens in row major. So then i should append instead of prepend right? You're prepending now.

Comment: Well, as my own matrix class now has the same results as the given library, i will just accept the fact that i'm still a noob, and move on. Thanks for helping me out twice today :) It is really apreciated.

Comment: That's the difference between row major and column major. rowMajorA * rowMajorB using rowMajorMultiply = columnMajorB * columnMajorA using columnMajorMultiply